# Forward all traffic to a subfolder and one subfolder to a different subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's a simplified version of the folder logic on my server.

```
├── rest/
│   └── api/
│       ├── account
│       ├── posts
│       └── settings
├── src/
│   ├── index.html
|   ├── scripts.js
│   └── about/
|       └── index.html
└── public/
    ├── index.html
    ├── scripts.js
    └── about/
        └── index.html
```

Server setup:
Ubuntu 16.04
Apache 2

What I am trying to achieve is this:

- acessing `/` will show content from `/public/index.html`
- accessing `/about` will show content from `/public/about/index.html`
- accessing `/api/account` will show content from `/rest/api/account`

Here's my current `.htaccess` setup

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,NC]
```

This works well for redirecting `/` to `/public/index.html` but not with the `api`.

Comment: `/about` to `/src/about/index.html` ?

Comment: @vivek_23 nope, to `/public/about/index.html` - my mistake, it was missing from the structure overview, updated now.

Comment: ok, does your current rule not give you too many redirects issue?

Comment: @vivek_23 I don't think it should - as I see it the rewrite is internal so the client shouldn't make the request again

Comment: @arco444 Apache does internal redirects even though URL remains the same. In this process, it shows a server error in the browser and `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error` in the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(api/.*)$ /rest/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I've been looking for for the past week! Could anyone recommend a good tutorial on Rewrite?